# Dynamically cast classes

Tags: java

I'm trying to do something along the lines:

```
abstract class Base {}

public interface One {...}
public interface Two {...}

public class A extends Base implements One {...}
public class B extends Base implements One, Two {...}
public class C extends Base implements Two {...}

public class Container
{
 class Handler
 {
  public void doSomething(A obj){System.out.println("A");}
  public void doSomething(B obj){System.out.printLn("B");}
  public void doSomething(C obj){System.out.println("C");}
 }
 Base base;
 Handler handler;
 public Container(Base base)
 {
  this.base = base;
  this.handler=new Handler();
 }
 public void set(Base base)
 {
  this.base=base;
 }
 public void go()
 {
  this.handler.doSomething(this.base);
 }
}


Container con=new Container(new A());
con.go();
con.set(new B());
con.go();
```

Where the output would end up being "A" "B", but I'm running into problems dynamically casting Container.base to the appropriate class;

The closest solution I have found is in the Container.go function add in an if else chain checking the instanceOf the class and casting the parameter to the corresponding class then calling handler.doSomething in each if block.

```
public void go()
{
 if(this.base instanceOf A)
 {
  this.handler.doSomething((A)this.base);
 }
 else if(this.base instanceOf B)
 ....
}
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Traditionally this would be handled with overriding (not overloading), so `foo.doSomething()` prints things, `doSomething()` is in an interface or superclass, and you don't use `instanceof`.

Comment: I didn't override doSomething since the logic within is strongly coupled with the the Container class.  The Base and subclasses are independent of the Container and Handler class. A, B, and C are closer to data structures containing slightly different information on top of what Base contains.

Comment: Yea, but the trick that works with overriding, doesn't work with overloading (due to static dispatch). So what are the A, B, Container, Holder, and Base classes really? I get code blind when given simplified code, so maybe you have a better design hiding underneath somewhere.

Comment: I'm working on a navigation type system.
Class Base is a Location, A, B, and C are Surface, Orbit, and Space locations. Where Surface and Space have a set of X Y coords that are independent of each other, and Orbit and Surface have a reference to the Orbital they are on. The Orbital has its own Space location as well.

The Container class is a Vehicle. The Handler is a Navigator. The overall objective is if vehicle is at a location how long does it take for it to get to another location.

Comment: I first had the Navigator as a class of static functions with 6 functions overloaded with the permutations of 'at' and 'target'.
Which worked great for design, but when I got into implementation I started running into the casting issues. A Vehicle only has one location, but it can contain or go to any type of locations. When triggering the Navigator, in most cases the 'target' Location class type is known, but not for the case that it is targeting another Vehicle.

Answer (score 2):

Which method is called is determined at compile time and not at run time so dynamic casting isn't going to work without some reflection or other tinkering about.  I would suggest a better approach is to move the logic for

```
  public void doSomething(A obj){System.out.println("A");}
  public void doSomething(B obj){System.out.printLn("B");}
  public void doSomething(C obj){System.out.println("C");}
```

Into the the specific classes.  For example:

```
abstract class Base {
    absract public void doSomething();
}

public class A extends Base implements One {
    public void doSomething() {System.out.printLn("A");}
}
...

class Handler {
    public void doSomething(Base obj){obj.doSomething();}
}
```

Now your handler doesn't need to care about the specific class of a Base object it is getting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the visitor pattern:

```
public interface Visitor {
  public void doSomething(A obj);
  public void doSomething(B obj);
  public void doSomething(C obj);
}
```

Declare an abstract method in `Base` (or in a new interface):

```
abstract class Base {
    public abstract void accept(Visitor v);
}
```

and implement it in A, B, C:

```
public class A extends Base implements One {
    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.doSomething(this);
    }
    ...
}
public class B extends Base implements One, Two {
    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.doSomething(this);
    }
    ...
}
public class C extends Base implements Two {
    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.doSomething(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

`Handler` implements `Visitor`:

```
class Handler implements Visitor {
    @Override
    public void doSomething(A obj){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    @Override
    public void doSomething(B obj){
        System.out.printLn("B");
    }
    @Override
    public void doSomething(C obj){
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}
```

And finally, `go` becomes:

```
public void go() {
    this.base.visit(this.handler);
}
```

UPDATE

Note that @Evan Jones' solution is simpler and it could be what you need. The visitor pattern is used when you want to separate the implementations of the `doSomething` methods from the A, B, C classes and/or you want the ability to add new operations without changing these classes.